# Can your muscle composition (fast / slow twitch) be altered?

Tags: muscle

Is this composition determined entirely by genetics? Or can training a certain way altered the composition?

Can someone go from 70/30 fast/slow to 30/70 fast/slow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So basically you have three types of muscle fibre:

- Type I (slow-twitch)
- Type IIa (fast oxidative)
- Type IIx (fast glycolytic)

Most people are generally born with roughly a 50/50 split between types I and II. Top level endurance athletes can have up to 90-95% type I fibres, whereas strength/power athletes can have 60-80% type II. It's generally believed that you can alter your makeup by around 10% either way (see [this article](https://www.outsideonline.com/1783586/it-possible-change-my-muscle-type)).

It's well established that it's possible to convert e.g. IIa to IIx with training, but it's less certain that you can actually convert type I to II (or vice-versa). What you *are* able to do is to target certain fibres with exercise so that the *proportion* of Type I to II fibres is altered.

A fun bit of anecdotal evidence - the marathon runner Alberto Salazar aimed to do sufficient endurance exercise that he lost his ability to jump, as his fast-twitch fibres had reduced to such an extent.

See [this review of the literature](https://journals.lww.com/nsca-jscr/FullText/2012/06000/The_Effects_of_Endurance,_Strength,_and_Power.37.aspx) for more details